# Choice of $b$ that maximizes $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x - a) f(x-b)dx$?

Tags: calculus, optimization, improper-integrals

I saw a statement that the choice of $b$ that maximizes $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x - a) f(x-b)dx$ is $b=a$. I guess this is equivalent to stating that the max of $g(b) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) f(x-b)dx$ is $b=0$, but I don't know how to prove it. It seems like it would be a well known result but don't know what to search for. I tried calculating $g'(b)$ but it doesn't really lead me anywhere and I'm unsure of the validity of the steps taken:

$$g'(b) =  \dfrac{d}{db}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) f(x-b)dx = (?) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \bigg(\dfrac{d}{db} f(x-b) \bigg)dx = \\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) f'(x-b)(-1)dx = - \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) f'(x-b) dx$$

Don't know if it's on the right path. Replacing the integrals with sums I think the statement makes sense, since then I think it's similar to the statement that the vector $y$ such that $|y|=|x|$ that maximizes $x \cdot y$, is $y=x$.

Would appreciate hints or the name of the theorem if it has a name, or a proof/proof sketch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it's similar to the statement that the vector $y$ such that $|y|=|x|$ that maximizes $x \cdot y$, is $y=x$.

Exactly, and that is because of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, which holds in all inner product spaces and can not only be applied to vector products, but also to integrals.

We must assume that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)^2 \, dx$ is finite. For  any $b\in \Bbb R$ is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) f(x-b) \, dx \le \left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2} \cdot \left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-b)^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)^2 \, dx 
$$
and equality holds for $b=0$.